# Put MQ record to Kinesis | Python Lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have python lambda function, which will get messages from AWS MQ and with those messages I need to put them into Kinesis.
I followed [this](http://%20https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Client.put_record) link but that did not help much. So Rob helped me to get through this.

My Final achievement is - I have my Kinesis in Different AWS account with Role name, ARN, StreamARN,Stream Name and Endpoint as well as the Partition Key. What changes do I need to do to my below code?

Code:

```
import time
import boto3
import stomp
import json

kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis')


class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message %s (%s)'%(message, headers))
        kinesis_client.put_record(
            StreamName='',
            Data=b'bytes',
            PartitionKey='1'
        )
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[('b-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
    lst = Listener()
    conn.set_listener('Listener', lst)
    conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[('b-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
    conn.start()
    print('CONNECTION Started')
    conn.connect(login='test_mq', passcode='',wait=True)
    print('CONNECTION established')
    conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/', id=1, ack='auto', headers={'transformation' : 'jms-map-json'})
    print('CONNECTION Subscribed')
    time.sleep(10)
    conn.disconnect()
    return
```

Comment: Don't you want to put the record `on_message` instead of `on_error` ?

Comment: @RobBricheno My bad accidentally copied .. Corrected it now. Captured new logs as well.

Comment: It looks like you need to give your lambda function permission to put records to your kinesis stream.

Comment: @RobBricheno- I gave AmazonKinesisFullAccess to my role. Now error message is gone:) But not able view the message in Kinesis GUI:'(

Comment: @RobBricheno-- I have my Kinesis in Different AWS account with Role name, ARN, StreamARN,Stream Name and Endpoint as well as the Partition Key. What changes do I need to more do to my below code. Please suggest

Comment: @RobBricheno- I have updated my code, just wanted to check whether my code is right and will accept Json file as input and send it to kinesis?